# Are there any hard-line anti-Russian parties in Europe?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, parties

The Russian invasion of Ukraine has highlighted the degree, and risks, of Europe's economic ties to Russia. I wonder if there is a party that takes a hardline anti-Russian stance?

The positions I'm asking about go beyond "economic sanctions" toward a more aggressive policy: "remove all Russian ties and make sure Russians are no longer in the EU, prepare to invade Russia for safety and make sure the government is no longer so anti-Europe and more friendly controlled by the EU"?

Are there any parties in the EU that take this or a similar position?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're asking about a specific country, any country's parties, or specifically the European Parliament or other EU-level institutions?

Comment: The most if not all parties in Poland and Baltic states a very anti-russian. However, can´t think of any party to be crazy enough to ask for invading Russia.

Comment: @divibisan I live in the netherlands, but all parties are members of group of parties in the european parliament - so I wonder which group is planning to invade and destroy russia?

Comment: No one is planning to invade or destroy Russia, nor could they.

Comment: You might have more luck if you remove the part about invading Russia. No serious party will suggest that, but it wouldn't surprise me if there was a party that proposed total economic isolation.

Comment: @divibisan There are even parties in East Europe proposing giving lethal weapons to Ukraine.

Comment: "make sure Russians are no longer in the EU" is an ECHR violation, that's literally ethnic cleansing :( It also runs hard into the usual problems: Russians married to EU nationals? Half-Russians? People who are entitled to Russian citizenship but do not have a Russian passport?

Comment: @pjc: There _are_ hard-line anti-muslim parties that call for similar measures, so this question is not that far-fetched. And a slightly less extreme position (revoke all visa) might pass ECHR muster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The positions I'm asking about go beyond "economic sanctions" toward a more aggressive policy: "remove all Russian ties and make sure Russians are no longer in the EU, prepare to invade Russia for safety and make sure the government is no longer so anti-Europe and more friendly controlled by the EU"?
>
> Are there any parties in the EU that take this or a similar position?

There are no such parties. What you are describing, to invade Russia, is a very aggressive position. Attacking Russia would:

- Violate Russia's territorial integrity
- Start a direct conflict with a nuclear power

The two reasons above make it such an extreme position that I'm confident enough that no significant political party in Europe advocates an invasion of Russia.

Another way of reasoning is to look at Russia's intervention in Ukraine. An intervention by the West to aid Ukraine against Russia would be a less aggressive step which goes beyond sanctions.

Already, few if any in the West seem to be in favor of deploying their own military to Ukraine to help fight off the Russian invasion. If it's deemed too risky to fight against Russia in and alongside Ukraine, then it's certainly too risky to fight Russia in its own territory.

Comment: "Vote for us and get nuked!" isn't the strongest platform.